# making pdflatex look in the right place for texlive

Tags: installing, texlive, paths

I have followed the install instructions for texlive for unix, and have set the path permanently - i.e. "echo $PATH" gives the following output -

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/jtait/.script:/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux
```

(the correct texlive directory being at the end). Also, tlmgr is working fine, so it certainly is the right path.

However, when I run pdflatex everything it loads is in /user/share, and it using this version:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
```

If I remove tex-live (which I thought I had - I since purged it), it still won't work.

Is there something other than setting the path that I should be doing? I don't know if this is pdflatex specific.

I am on an Ubuntu install, 13.04.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325994/setting-path-with-two-different-texlive-versions) on the Ubuntu stack exchange appears to be related (though with no answers).

I left all the install options as default, in case that is relevant.

Comment: Check which pdflatex is the one used with `which pdflatex`? Have you checked that the path to your manual texlive install is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$PATH` environment uses whatever is defined first as the command. Eg. : `PATH=<dir1>:<dir2>` If the command appears in both directories, the `<dir1>` will still be the one used. Try moving the texlive bin directory to the beginning of the `$PATH` environment.

Comment: That's great, thank you very much for the help.